# Writing to a database in django

Tags: django, django-models

In django I can find a lot of examples of reading a database and displaying the data accordingly on a webpage. **I can find no example of writing back to the database** though (according to user input, or to the result of a computation). Can you point me to example code, or a tutorial or help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is concerned about inserting data in the db, You can write back to the database in Django through views.py.
You can refer to these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35602179/16136191
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35602287/16136191

Otherwise, you can also write data directly using the `\admin` site.
If you're looking to write data from the webpage, you can check out how forms work in Django.
I hope that helps.